# Keep img ratio with jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, width

Over 910px, I have a fixed img that takes 100% of the window in height and has a width: auto;. On load, the image has always the good proportions, but when I scale down (from the bottom) it distorts itself.

The width stays the same and doesn't scale down.

The image is contained in a .picture div :

```
.picture {
float: left;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
```

Example : [image]

Is there a way to force the image to keep it's original ratio, maybe using jQuery?  The content on the right already changes its width in function of the image width.

Here's the template : http://bettercheckthekids.com/pirlo/index.html

Comment: post code here....random url's not suggested for seeking answer!! :)

Comment: Works like expected in Safari 7.0.1

Comment: @Lars Beck : Strange because when I resize from the bottom in Safari 7.0.1 the ratio is not good.

Comment: @cfocket Damn, I read over "from the bottom"... giving the image `max-width: 100%;` should solve the issue, furthermore `width: auto;` is default.

Comment: @LarsBeck: It's better but my script adapting the right content width doesn't run so good anymore. When I increase the window again it has troubles calculating the new width of the picture. Well, that's something else to work on. Thx again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest you a alternative way to solve your problem. if you use bootstrap you can involve a div to make resizable image.

```
 <div class="img-responsive">
     <img src="test.jpg" width='xxx' height='yyy' alt='test'>
  </div>
```